# Separate table in case of surrogate key?

Tags: sql, join, indexing, view, surrogate-key

I have been reading the heated debates on composite vs surrogate keys on Stack Overflow and other websites, and even though puzzled about some of the arguments given, I feel I am aware of the pros and cons of each.

I feel tempted to go for surrogate keys, but now I have another question. Let me explain my situation. I have a table consisting of 5 integers that make up a unique combination, and I have several tables referencing this entity. Right now all tables include the full 5 fields and all JOIN operations have to mention all 5 fields as a join criterium. Now I have added a surrogate key. But should I remove all 5 fields from all tables in favour of a surrogate foreign key that references the 'main' table?

I feel unsure about doing this, since each of the 5 fields separately is frequently used as a selection criterium in the other tables. I have indexes defined on them, in a certain natural order, so that the selection operations perform fast. If I migrate all 5 fields to a separate table, I'm afraid that when I want to select on let's say the first three of them, I'll have to define a JOIN and select from that, but no indexes will have been defined on that JOIN since it has just been generated, and I will suffer a performance loss.

Or should I somehow define a VIEW for each table, including the 5 keys, and index on that?

I feel confused, and after typing all this, inclined to stick with natural keys again.
Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to have one table with your 5 unique fields + surrogate PRIMARY KEY. In that table you can create indexes on each of the fields + unique constraint on 5 fields. Then, instead of having 5 fields in other tables you, will have just 1 column .

Comment: Hm, yes, and then I can put an index on that one and JOIN with the other tables, so my filters will be quick as well.

I'll just try both approaches and compare performance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very specific goal for introducing a surrogate key, I'd probably leave it alone as long as it works for you.